# How many minimal relations are needed to obtain a Frobenius algebra?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, frobenius-algebras

Let $A_n:=K \langle x_1,x_2,...,x_n \rangle$ be the non-commutative polynomial ring in $n$-variables over the field $K$ and let $J=\langle x_1,...,x_n \rangle$ be the ideal spanned by the $x_i$.
An ideal $I$ of $A_n$ is called admissible if $J^m \subseteq I \subseteq J^2$ for some $m \geq 2$.

Call a relation contained in an admissible ideal $I$ standard if it is of the form $x_i x_j - q_{i,j} x_j x_i$ with field elements $q_{i,j} \neq 0$ and $i \neq j$. The ideals we consider are only allowed to contain one standard relation for each $(i,j)$ in a generating set of $I$.

An algebra of the form $A_n/I$ with admissible $I$ is called a local quiver algebra and a local quiver algebra is a Frobenius algebra if and only if the socle of the regular module is one-dimensional, which is equivalent to the purely combinatorial condition that there is a unique longest element up to a scalar (longest in the sense that multiplying it with any other element in $J$ gives zero).

> Question 1: Let $B=A_n/I$ be a local quiver algebra and assume that $B$ is Frobenius.
> What is the minimal number of needed non-standard relations that generate $I$ for a fixed $n$?

Call this minimal number $a(n)$. Do we have $a(n) = n$?

Note that in the commutative case, being Frobenius is the same as being Gorenstein, so this question might have been considered there before. The examples $K[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_1^2,...,x_n^2)$ have exactly $n$ non-standard relations (the standard relations here give exactly commutativity).

My guess translates into the following for commutative rings:

> Let $R=K[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ be a commutative algebra with Krull dimension 0. If $A$ is Gorenstein, then $I$ contains at least $n$ minimal generators. Is this true?

And this should be true in the commutative case, see for example the corollary in page 5 of [https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/615W10/supDim.pdf](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ehochster/615W10/supDim.pdf) .
Namely, in the commutative case we $dim R \geq n - k$, where $k$ is the number of minimal generators of $I$.

For $n=1$ the only algebras here are $K[x]/(x^l)$, so $a(1)=1$.

For $n=2$ the questions is whether an algebra of the form $K\langle x_1,x_2 \rangle/I$ can be a Frobenius algebra where $I=\langle x_1 x_2-q x_2 x_1 , U_1 \rangle $ with $U_1$ a single other admissible relation and $q \neq 0$. My feeling is that this should not be possible, so that we have $a(2)=2$. But it might be not so easy to show as there are examples like $K \langle x_1,x_2 \rangle / I$ with $I=\langle x_1 x_2+2x_2 x_1, x_1^4+x_2^2 \rangle$ that is finite-dimensional with 2-dimensional socle (so that it is not Frobenius, but close).

Call the number of minimal non-standard generators in $I$ the size of $I$.

> Question 2: Given a  fixed local quiver algebra that is Frobenius. How can one determine the size of $I$, that is how can one find a minimal set of generators of $I$ that are needed to generate $I$ together with the standard relations?

Comment: I think you are asking not about relations contained in the ideal but rather about generating set of the ideal, i.e. whether a generating set must contain at least $n$ non-standard relations. In this generating set, we are only allowed one standard relation for each pair $i,j$, right? We can't double up to force $x_i x_j = x_jx_i=0$.

Comment: @WillSawin Yes, thanks. Ill edit.